# не работает скрипт, ошибок консоль не выдает, все другие скрипты работают

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, mobile-web

```
$(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() < 540 + 'px') {
            $( '#input' ).innerHTML = ('<div  id="input" class="settings__block-title settings__block-hover">Монтаж межкомнатных... <img class="down-icon-inside" src="img/icon-down.png"></div>');
        } else {
            $( '#input' ).innerHTML = ('<div  id="input" class="settings__block-title settings__block-hover">Монтаж межкомнатных перегородок ИХ ГКЛ конструкций <img class="down-icon-inside" src="img/icon-down.png"></div>');
        }
    });
```

Нужно менять содержимое дива, когда окно меньше 540px

Comment: `540 + 'px' != 540` . Функция width возвращает число

Comment: Сравнение строк в JS работает не так, как с числами. К тому же `.width` все равно возвращает **_число_**, а не строку. Так что добавлять `'px'` к 540 бессмысленно.